# Odoo force a field higher than x

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

In sales order, there is a field discount %. Is it possible to ensure the users only input value lower than x and it will not accept any value higher than x.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with creating a function using `@api.onchange('discount')` decorator on python code to ensure discount value is not higher than `x`, if higher then set `x` to discount field and also possible to show warning popup from that function.

But if python code change is not prefered, you can also achieve this with `Automated action` where you create a new rule on `sale.order.line`, set trigger `On form modification`, action `Execute python code` and add the following code
if record.discount > 10:
record.discount = 10

Where 10 is the value of `x`. This will ensure discount is always less than `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Op1: If you want to ensure that behaviour you can add an `sql constraint` to the database, this will work fine if your `X` value never change, something like this:

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('discount_less_than_X', 'CHECK(discount < X)', 'The discount value should be less than X'),
]
```

This constraint will trigger in all cases(create, write, import, SQL insert).

Replace X with the value desired.

Op2: Use decorator `api.constrains`, get `X` value from somewherelse and apply the restriccion, something like this:

```
@api.constrains('discount')
def _check_discount(self):
    # Create a key:value parameter in `ir.config_parameter` table before.
    disscount_max_value = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('disscount_max_value')
    for rec in self:
       if rec.disscount > int(disscount_max_value):
           raise ValidationError('The discount value should be less than {}'.format(disscount_max_value))
```

I hope this answer can be helful for you.